# Working voltage vs dielectric withstanding voltage

Tags: voltage, resistors, dielectric-breakdown

What is the difference between *working voltage* and *dielectric withstanding voltage* in resistor components? Or both the working voltage and dielectric withstanding voltage is same? Can I apply the working voltage value to the dielectric withstanding voltage?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by working voltage - a spark plug's working voltage is potentially larger (when initiating an arc) than the dielectric of the gas between electrodes.

Comment: Add clarifications to your question and don't leave solely as comments. Be more specific - provide a link to the component data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Working voltage: Voltage that the device can safely and reliably be used.

Dielectric Withstanding Voltage: Voltage at which the device exhibits breakdown such as arcing or degradation of materials.